# Can I cast lightning bolt as an opportunity attack using War Caster Feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, opportunity-attack

Can I cast lightning bolt as an opportunity attack using War Caster Feat?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Consider taking the [tour] as it's a useful introduction to how things work around here. Is there any chance you can expand upon your question a bit more? Is there a reason you think this can or can't be done? Is there a particular rule, part of a rule, or just ambiguous wording that has led to your confusion? It helps us to know what specifically has you confused so that we don't over explain or write up a completely useless answer because you've already looked at X rules but haven't mentioned so in the question. Brevity *can* be fine, but more explanation is always good.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, you can't. To be cast as an opportunity attack with War Caster:

> The spell must have a casting time of 1 action and must target only that creature.

However, *Lightning Bolt* is an area of effect spell. The Spellcasting chapter, under Targets, says:

> A
>   spell’s
>   description
>   tells
>   you
>   whether
>   the
>   spell
>   targets
>   creatures,
>   objects,
>   or
>   a
>   point
>   of
>   origin
>   for
>   an
>   area
>   of
>   effect
>   (described
>   below).

So the target of *Lightning Bolt* is its point of origin. Ok, so what's *Lightning Bolt*'s point of origin? Well, its Range is given as Self (100-foot line). The Range section has this to say:

> Spells
>   that
>   create
>   cones
>   or
>   lines
>   of
>   effect
>   that
>   originate
>   from
>   you
>   also
>   have
>   a
>   range
>   of
>   self,
>   indicating
>   that
>   the
>   origin
>   point
>   of
>   the
>   spell’s
>   effect
>   must
>   be
>   you
>   (see
>   “Areas
>   of
>   Effect”).

That being the case, the point of origin (and therefore the target) of *Lightning Bolt* is you. As such, you cannot use it with War Caster.

Comment: It is worth noting that the spell resulting from war caster is not, in fact, an opportunity attack, but is a special reaction in place of an opportunity attack. This often trips people up, so it might be worth adding to the answer.

Answer (score 12):

### No.

The war caster feat specifies that you can only cast a spell that targets one creature:

> The spell must have a casting time of 1 action and must target only that creature.

Lightning bolt is an AOE spell:

> A stroke of lightning forming a line 100 feet long and 5 feet wide blasts out from you in a direction you choose.

Therefore, it does not meet the single-target criteria.